# What does the pubspec.yaml's environment mean in this context?

Tags: dart

I notice the environment variable in the intl package's [pubspec.yaml](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/blob/master/pubspec.yaml) says that it supports between the sdk '1.4.0 to 2.0.0'

I found the description of the environment variable [here](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec.html#sdk-constraints)

But, That particular version's [numer_format.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/blob/master/lib/src/intl/number_format.dart) has the null aware operators that are not introduced until 1.12.0.

Am I understanding the definition of the pubspec's environment variable correctly?

Thanks

Comment: A little thank for finding the problem with null-aware operators and the SDK constraint in the `intl` package. EDIT: see my comments to Alexandre Ardhuin answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
environment:
  sdk: '>1.3.0 <= 2.0.0'
```

is not related to operating system environment variables, it is just a constraint for the environment where the package is supposed to work, and the only setting currently supported is the Dart SDK version. The version range is according to the semantic versioning used in Dart for the SDK and pub packages.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct the SDK constraint should be modified to something like `>=1.12.0 <2.0.0`. You can [file an issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/new) (or even better submit a Pull-request).

Comment: Pull request submitted (https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/pull/103). Let's wait...

Comment: Pull request merged :) Version 0.12.7 of `intl` package will use the right SDK constraint.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 1):

```
environment:
sdk: ">=2.16.1 <=3.1.0"
```

This means the Dart SDK version.

packages & dependencies of your project must be supported above the SDK range.